# C++ Bit Representation of a Double

Tags: c++, compression, double, ieee-754

My understanding was that doubles are stored based on the IEEE 754-2008 standard in C++, where the first bit is the sign, the following 11 are the exponents and the remaining 52 are the fraction. However, the code below + output shows something else.

Code

```cpp
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    
    double value_float = 1.5;
    uint64_t value_uint = 0;


    std::memcpy(&value_uint, &value_float, 8);
    std::cout << value_uint << std::endl;

    std::bitset<64>doubleBitset(value_uint);
    std::cout << "DoubleBitset for " << value_float << " is: ";
    std::cout << doubleBitset << std::endl;

}
```

Output: `DoubleBitset for 1.5 is: 0011111111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

Why isn't the output `0b0 - 00000000001  1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000;`

Comment: What is the output from `std::cout << value_uint << std::endl;`?

Comment: Whether C++ floating point numbers are IEEE 754 compliant depend on the implementation, but it is _usually_ the case, yes.

Answer (score 8):

The `double` stores the exponent biased. This means that essentially it is stored as an unsigned integer and whenever it is used `1023` is subtracted. This will essentially mean that positive numbers will have their first bit set, while `0` will only have that bit unset. A good overview on the standard is the [Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64).

Back to the question if we calculate the representation manually we get: 1) First bit is `0` since positive. 2) The exponent needs to be `0` so it is set to `0b01111111111` as that represents a `0` exponent. 3) The mantissa will be what you expect, i.e. one bit set at the start then 51 zeros.

Edit: As pointed out in the comments there are some special meaning in the exponent in some cases. If the exponent is `2047` then if all of the mantissa is `0` then it represents `Inf` or `-Inf`. If the mantissa is not all `0` if the previous case, then the value is `NaN`. To represent zero the mantissa must be `0` with exponent `0` as well. I like to think of these as special cases rather than a code, since most of these are conditional on the other parts of the double's representation, but Eric Postpischil's comment is an other way to think about this.

Comment: The exponent field is better described as a code rather than a biased exponent, since not all of its values are a biased exponent, and the values convey additional information. Code 2047 indicates an infinity or a NaN, codes 1-2046 indicate exponents −1022 to +1023 and **also** indicate the first bit of the significand is 1, and code 0 indicates exponent −1022 (same as 1) and **also** indicates the first bit of the significand is 0.